# Retrieve, Display and Download attachments in Salesforce Community

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I want to display attachments in my customer Community but nothing is showing .
Can anyone help me how to retrieve ,display and download attachments in salesforce community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000A4iKIAS)

- Community Users do not have access to attachments for Contacts and
  Accounts (this is a limitation), you can see that by loading the
  contact record in the layout after you've logged in as community
  user.
- We've confirmed that OWD would not come into play for community users, thus, even though OWD for account is Public Read Write (Contact - Controlled by Parent), this would not have effect for Community User.
- This is a limitation for community users and the workaround is to create a custom object and have it related to Contact and then have the files attached to this custom object instead of Contact. Once the community user has taken ownership of the record and attachment, they will then able to see and open the attachment.